# Hiding Keypad within Fragment

Tags: android, keyboard

I am getting these errors when trying to hide the keyboard inside a fragment within an activity:

> Error: Cannot resolve getSystemService
>
> Cannot resolve Context
>
> Cannot resolve getCurrentFocus()

```
 InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
 InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Inside a fragment you should use getActivity(),

```
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: Reolved It Works Great Firass

Comment: It's generally advisable to check whether getActivity() returns null or not. Orientation changes in particular can cause getActivity() to return null briefly, since orientation changes cause the activity to be destroyed and recreated while the fragment persists. A common approach in situations like this is for the fragment to "ask" (e.g., via event bus) its activity to perform an action like this that requires the activity (`getSystemService()` can't be called directly in the fragment). See https://hackernoon.com/8-ways-to-communicate-between-fragment-and-activity-in-android-apps-235b60005d04.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I've never had any luck with closing a keyboard from a fragment.  I dont understand the engineering behind it but here is what works.

MainActivity-

```
public void closeKeyboard() {
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
private void closeKeyboard() {
    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    mainActivity.closeKeyboard();

}
```

Then just call your method closeKeyboard() whereever you want in the Fragment

Comment: How about just putting the code in `closeKeyboard()` in MainActivity in the fragment's `closeKeyboard()` instead, but with `getActivity()` in front of `getSystemService` in the second to last line (so, `InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);`. That way there's no need for the `closeKeyboard()` in MainActivity.

If that doesn't work or there's another reason for not doing that, please explain.